# ng-repeat not updating in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am currently to implement a small drag and drop ranking question with angular. Everything seems to be working fine except in Chrome where the labels for the ranking question aren't updating correctly.

I have recreated the problem in [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jHH5sqcrdlYauzYWpNqi). To recreate the problem drag all options into the drop area (the grey bit) and then switch the first with the second place. Now the first two items should display the same $index and label when doing this in Chrome.

When I switch to another tab and come back to the page it has updated correctly. It looks like it just isn't repainting for some reason.

I had a look in the model with Batarang and everything looks correct in there. I have run an additional $digest cycle by hand to see if there was a problem there, but it seemed fine.

The issue seems to only affect Chrome for some reason. If I recreate it on Firefox it works fine.

Comment: The code is quite extensive to go though, and I would have done allot of things differently. But Overall it appears like your missing an Apply somewhere, if you do the re-arange that provoke the error, then start dragging again on another element, but without actually rearranging (which probably triggers a digest somewhere) you can actually get the element to update. But then again, since it works in IE... it is obviously odd...

Comment: (Ran out of space) Often I find Chrome to be more aligned with standards, but there may ofc. also be a bug in Chrome, I have seen Chrome, i guess it makes sense to bring this to Angular as an issue?.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking it might be an $apply somewhere, but I thought running an additional $digest cycle by hand would then update it regardless and Firefox should have the same issue in that case.

Comment: Ever find a fix for this issue?

Comment: I _think_ using track by fixed it, but it has been a long time and I can't remember, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've been recently working on one old project - it was using angular 1.2.6. And I met same issue.
Updating to version 1.2.29 helped me.

I know it's a little bit late but still may help to somebody :)